# UIButton in UISegmentedView not getting pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uisegmentedcontrol

I placed a custom UIButton in one of my UISegments of a UISegmentedView but somehow this button is not getting pressed. 
I use following code:

```
UIButton* button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 103, 30);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSaleChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[[[self.segmentControl subviews]objectAtIndex:2] addSubview:button];
[self.segmentControl bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Any idea why I am experiencing this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That button is a *subview of a subview*, so it won't be firing any time soon, seeing as the segmented control would capture its touches anyhow.  Add it as a subview of the control and try again.

Comment: nice thought! I tired that just now but as soon as I touch the button it disappears in the background and the view of the segment comes into the foreground. Eventually the button still does not get pressed.

Comment: Wow, at least you know what to do.  Call `-bringSubviewToFront:` when the button is pressed and see if that helps.

Comment: Didn't work either. However I now just added the button to my view over the segmentcontrol and I then manually switch the selected segment in the button handler. By that the looks of the control remains preserved and the button also gets pressed. Thanks for your thoughts, though!

Comment: And with that, I bow out.  Maybe if you made a guthub gist or something, I could help you, but this is an interesting problem.  +1